# Read PDf from all the pages

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read and print the text from all the PDF pages (59 pages).
I was able to print it but getting this error.

This is the code i have used.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader(r'C:\Users\Dinesh\Downloads\1r41ai10801601_fong.pdf')
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
print(type(number_of_pages))

i=0
for i in range(number_of_pages):
    page = reader.pages[i+1]
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)
```

Is there a way we can avoid this error?

ERROR is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sdvs.png)

Comment: Where is the error ? Please post the error.

Comment: Thank you..Yes.,
Just added the error screenshot

Comment: The problem might be that the i+1 may be causing the index to go out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
# importing required modules 
import PyPDF2 
    
# creating a pdf file object 
pdfFileObj = open('C:\\your_file.pdf', 'rb') 
    
# creating a pdf reader object 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 
    
# printing number of pages in pdf file 
print(pdfReader.numPages) 
    
# creating a page object 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 
    
# extracting text from page 
print(pageObj.extractText()) 
    
# closing the pdf file object 
pdfFileObj.close()
```